# Meaning of "a rap on the knuckles"

Tags: phrase-meaning, translation

How do you perform the action of "a rap on the knuckles" physically? Would you perform it on one's forehead as a slight and not serious punishment or warning? In China we call such an action "give someone a chestnut" as the shape of the knuckles resembles that of a chestnut. I am considering if the two phrases are equivalent in translation.

Comment: You may be describing a noogie https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/noogie

Comment: Note the difference between a rap _on/over_ the knuckles (using something else to hit the knuckles) and a rap _with_ the knuckles (using your knuckles to hit something, such as a door or – indeed – someone’s head). I’m not familiar with the Chinese expression, and Googling things like 打栗子 or 给栗子 doesn’t yield anything useful, so I can’t really tell which one it’s referring to.

Answer (score 4):

> how do you perform the action of "a rap on the knuckles" physically?

By hitting someone's hand, specifically their knuckles, with a ruler or similar object.

> Would you perform it on one's forehead as a slight and not serious
> punishment or warning?

It would be on the knuckles, and you wouldn't do it. This is illegal in most native English speaking locations. This is a phrase which is used figuratively and rarely literally. It stems from when nuns would hit children in Catholic school (and other schools) a long time ago, and in some areas, to this day.

Comment: not only nuns..

Comment: It was a traditional mild punishment used in schools in general, certainly not limited to Catholic schools.